# ffmpeg entropy/bitplanenoise/freezedetect filters correct usage

Tags: ffmpeg

I am writing a node js package aimed at testing video streams.

I want to implement such features as measuring entropy, bit plane noise and freeze detect wrapping the corresponding ffmpeg filters.

Currently i am having problems doing this (which i assume is the problem of incorrect syntax use):

1. Seems my current version of ffmpeg (4.1.3) does not support freeze detect filter:

   `ffmpeg -filters | grep freeze
   ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
   built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
   configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
   libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
   libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
   libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
   libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
   libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
   libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
   libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
   libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
   libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100`

   `ffmpeg -i simps_mpeg.mp4 -vf freezedetect -f null -
   ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
   built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
   configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
   libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
   libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
   libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
   libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
   libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
   libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
   libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
   libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
   libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'simps_mpeg.mp4':
   Metadata:
   major_brand     : isom
   minor_version   : 512
   compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
   encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
   Duration: 00:00:09.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1129 kb/s
   Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1128 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k tbc (default)
   Metadata:
     handler_name    : Core Media Video
   Stream mapping:
   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
   Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
   [AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fb1a1d13ec0] No such filter: 'freezedetect'
   Error reinitializing filters!
   Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
   Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
   Conversion failed!`
2. entropy filter does not output anything related to entropy measurement

   `ffmpeg -i simps_mpeg.mp4 -vf entropy -f null -
   ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
   built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
   configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
   libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
   libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
   libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
   libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
   libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
   libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
   libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
   libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
   libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'simps_mpeg.mp4':
   Metadata:
   major_brand     : isom
   minor_version   : 512
   compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
   encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
   Duration: 00:00:09.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1129 kb/s
   Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1128 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k tbc (default)
   Metadata:
     handler_name    : Core Media Video
   Stream mapping:
   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
   Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
   Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
   Metadata:
   major_brand     : isom
   minor_version   : 512
   compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
   encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
   Stream #0:0(und): Video: wrapped_avframe, yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
   Metadata:
     handler_name    : Core Media Video
     encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 wrapped_avframe
   frame=  233 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:09.71 bitrate=N/A speed=25.7x
   video:122kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown`
3. same problem with bitplanenoise filter - no output with bit plane noise measurement:

   `ffmpeg -i simps_mpeg.mp4 -vf bitplanenoise -f null -
   ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
   built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
   configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
   libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
   libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
   libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
   libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
   libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
   libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
   libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
   libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
   libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'simps_mpeg.mp4':
   Metadata:
   major_brand     : isom
   minor_version   : 512
   compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
   encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
   Duration: 00:00:09.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1129 kb/s
   Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1128 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k tbc (default)
   Metadata:
     handler_name    : Core Media Video
   Stream mapping:
   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
   Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
   Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
   Metadata:
   major_brand     : isom
   minor_version   : 512
   compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
   encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
   Stream #0:0(und): Video: wrapped_avframe, yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
   Metadata:
     handler_name    : Core Media Video
     encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 wrapped_avframe
   frame=  233 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:09.71 bitrate=N/A speed=12.2x
   video:122kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown`

Regarding freezedetect: is this filter outdated?

ffpmeg ver. 4.1.3, OS: MacOS Mojave 10.14.5

Comment: No, but your FFmpeg version is surely outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a recent git build to have freezedetect included - get one from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/.

As far as bitplanenoise and entropy are concerned, they print their data as metadata entries. So, you need to add the metadata filter and set its mode to print to get that data.

e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i simps_mpeg.mp4 -vf bitplanenoise,metadata=mode=print:file=- -f null -
```

This will print the data to console.

To dump to file,

```
ffmpeg -i simps_mpeg.mp4 -vf bitplanenoise,metadata=mode=print:file=simps_mpeg_bpn.log -f null -
```